Fontscripts package reinstallation fails due to zero file size error
I'm trying to reinstall the fontscripts package but its always failing with the following error; the file size indicates its size 0.

ERROR DETAILS Program: miktex-console Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\RepositoryManifest.h:100 Error: Unknown archive file size. Details: package: fontscripts


welcome! I would post a request on MikTeX's github bug tracker if you want it to be included in the distribution. but could I ask why you want to install it exactly?

looks like a packaging bug. Report it to the miktex tracker.

Indeed, https://miktex.org/packages/fontscripts currently shows "Packaged on: 01/01/0001 00:00:00 Number of files: 0 Size on disk: 0 bytes".

@UlrikeFischer I'm not sure how miktex splits packages, but it looks roughly right to me: fontscripts_source is the actual package and fontscripts is just a placeholder because there isn't anything except source and documentation. https://miktex.org/packages/fontscripts__source

but it would be better to get the development version from codeberg or github if you want to actually try to use it. this is incompletely documented, but the code is slightly saner. probably there shouldn't be a fontscripts at all, though ...?

@cfr no, the current status looks definitively wrong. But it is really not clear what should be how installed in your package. In texlive I find only the pdf. So it is probably understandable that miktex is confused.

@UlrikeFischer texlive has everything I'd expect in source/fonts/fontscripts? there really isn't anything to install: there's just the PDF as documentation. it's not clear to me how to say where things should go now ctan doesn't want tds archives, but there really isn't much to tell in this case.
